# What is this circular metal object embedded in spalled concrete?

Tags: civil-engineering, reinforced-concrete

Consider the piece of spalled concrete shown in the attached image. It has spalled due to the corrosion of the reinforcement bar. There is a small circular piece of metal embedded within the spalled concrete. What is it?

[image]

Additional image of circular objects still in-situ in reinforced concrete air tower structures:

[image]

Additional close up image of concrete plug containing metalic horseshoe like object from another part of the wall.

[image]

Comment: A picture of the object that is in focus would certainly help.

Comment: Is there an image of the other side? - _i.e._ where the spalled part came from.

Comment: @Fred I've added another photo to the question.

Comment: I think we need better photos.  I note that there isn't any staining around the circular thing in the 'what is this' photo, so why do you say it's metallic?  The location in the second photo, if that concrete element is relatively narrow into the page, is possibly the location of through-ties for the shutter when it was cast.  It might be a connector or end piece associated with them.  However, at the moment, the photos aren't any more help than saying 'what's round and in concrete?'

Comment: @achrn I've added another close up photo of the plug of concrete that comes easily away from the wall. The walls are 12" thick so it could easily be a metalic cone piece associated with the formwork tie rods. See the plastic cone here http://www.concrete.org.uk/images/fingertips/tiebolt.jpg

Comment: Were these poured in place? The column may be former ties. You have to hold the sides together with rods so the form doesn't bulge. https://www.trusupply.com/8-x-8-1/4-standard-snap-tie-w/1-cone-100-pc/box.html?feed=Froogle&_vsrefdom=adwords&gclid=CjwKCAiAudD_BRBXEiwAudakX_HL2eKocFwYbgPahqe9sdEpU_mlp87M5Obu_TbPEQ7bCyALiXY7bxoCpcYQAvD_BwE

Comment: @egg soemthing like that would be my best guess - maybe they used a metal conduit rather than what is shown as expendible plastic in that diagram?  Then removed the rods and cones, filling with grout and what you now have is that plug of grout coming out with staining on the end from the end of the conduit?  But I'm not sure why horseshoe shaped, and I don't think I've seen metal cones at the ends of ties, so it's not a decisive conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a prestressed cable anchor.

[image]

Comment: If it's a prestress cable anchor, where's the prestress cable gone?  This seems incredibly unlikely to me.  You'd see the prestress cable sticking out from where the concrete came from, or if it has pulled out of the concrete sticking out from the anchor.  If it let go suddenly you'd expect a lot of damage to the concrete.

Comment: As far as I am aware the reinforced concrete structure in question is not prestressed.

Comment: @achrn: I'm not convinced it's a prestressed anchor either, but it seems to be the most plausible explanation to me. It may have been a temporary aspect of the column (construction support for the beams?) which was later removed and the duct was then filled with grout or something. I'm not wholly convinced because it'd be cheaper to just leave that prestressed support after its actual period of use, but it's the best idea I have. I've designed many columns with prestressed supports at the top, but those were where the beams would rest, so not exactly applicable to this case, but still...

Comment: The other option is a lifting anchor. There are a lot of different types. They are usually recessed and patched over after erection. Most have some sort of mushroom head that is captured by a slotted lifting eye. With pretentioned cables, the ends are torched off flush so you can pull the piece out of the form.